# Why isn't my GridSplitter showing up?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, grid, gridsplitter

I have a simple `Window` that looks like this:

```
<Window x:Class="StackOverflowExample.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="3*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="2*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Label Content="Foo" Margin="5" />
        <Label Grid.Row="1" Content="Bar" Margin="5" />
        <GridSplitter Grid.Row="1" Background="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="5" />
    </Grid>
</Window>

// The code-behind is empty, except for "InitializeComponent()".
```

When I run the application, however, no `GridSplitter` is visible. I also see no `GridSplitter` during design time.

- I've made sure that the `GridSplitter` is in the correct row, and set the `VerticalAlignment` to `Top`
- I've specified an explicit background color to make sure that the `GridSplitter` does not blend in.
- I've made sure that the `GridSplitter` is the last element in the `Grid`, so I shouldn't be running into `ZIndex` problems.
- Just in case, I've added margins to the Labels to make sure that they are not obscuring the grid (although this should make a difference in this case).

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to set `HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"`:

```
<GridSplitter Grid.Row="1" Background="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="5" />
```

Comment: That fixed it. I thought `Stretch` was the default. Is `GridSplitter` an exception, or am I confused about `HorizontalAlignment`?

Comment: @Matthew - The default for GridSplitter is actually `Right`. You can check out the static constructor of GridSplitter in ILSpy/Reflector.